# Setting up VPN - Thomson Modem, Asus Router, UPC as ISP and T-Mobile for my Phone

Tags: networking, router, vpn, modem

I have a Asus RT-AC66U AC1750 Router which provides a VPN Server. For the Connection it uses PPTP. This Router is connectet to my Thomson TWG87OUG Modem which provides me with a internet connection from UPC. The Modem is set to forward the 1723, which should be the Port form the PPTP.
So thats the basic setup. Now if I try to connect to the VPN Server with my Android Phone it tells me that the server does not react on the request.

I googled around but I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I already had some Problems with the Modem but with forwarding I could get https and ssh to work. But now I am stuck with the VPN.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also open port 47 to the GRE protocol. Port 1723 is the control path (`i.e.`, the setting up of the connection), but the real data go through port 47, in the GRE protocol.

Your router may have an option called `VPN Passthrough`, which you should enable in so far as GRE is concerned. Otherwise, forward port 47, allowing **all** protocols.

If you are on Windows, you may try commands like pptpsrv and pptpclnt to check the full accessibility of your server, `i.e.`, both ports.

Comment: I just can enable TCP, UDP or both. I also opend the Port 47 set it to both protocolls. But still no success :( Also I don't have a special VPN Passthrough but I have a dropdown on the forwarding menue where I can select "PPTP Server" which enables 1723 port.